# how to perform query to get max sum in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, max, having

I have this table:

```
cart_item_id (primary key)
user_id (int)
shop_item_id (int)
quantity (int)
is_checked_out (tinyint)
```

from this table i want to get the most selling item, which is the item that have the maximum checked out quantities, i developed this query, but it returned errors:

```
SELECT `shop_item_id`
FROM `cart` 
WHERE `is_checked_out` = 1 
group by `shop_item_id` 
having sum(`quantity`) > max( 
select sum(`quantity`) 
from `cart` 
where `is_checked_out` = 1 
group by `shop_item_id` )
```

the error is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select sum(`quantity`) from `cart` where `is_checked_out` = 1 group by `shop_ite' at line 1
```

so what is the wrong in my query?

Comment: If you have multiple such items, what do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order by the quantity and take the first record only

```
SELECT `shop_item_id`, sum(`quantity`) 
FROM `cart` 
WHERE `is_checked_out` = 1 
group by `shop_item_id` 
order by sum(`quantity`) desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Note, that in case of a tie only one item will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems with your query.  One that you are using `group by` in the subquery, which returns more than one row.  Another is that you have a subquery as an argument to max()`.  You can fix this with something like:

```
SELECT `shop_item_id`
FROM `cart` 
WHERE `is_checked_out` = 1 
group by `shop_item_id` 
having sum(`quantity`) = (select max(q)
                          from (select sum(`quantity`) as q
                                from `cart` 
                                where `is_checked_out` = 1 
                                group by `shop_item_id`
                               ) c
                         ) c;
```

This version of the query will return multiple rows, if appropriate because of ties for the highest quantity.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will do fine for you :

```
SELECT `shop_item_id`
    FROM `cart` 
    WHERE `is_checked_out` = 1  and 
           sum(`quantity`)>=max ( select sum(`quantity`) 
                                  from `cart`
                                  where `is_checked_out` = 1 
                                ) 
 limit 1 ;
```